# How to create/drop mongoDB database and collections from a golang (go language) program.?

Tags: database, mongodb, go, nosql, mongo-go

```
func DatabaseConnect() (db *mongo.Database, err error) {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 20*time.Second)
    defer cancel()
    client, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://localhost:27017"))
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    db = client.Database("students")
    return
}
```

this above function connects to a database which is already present on mongoDB server. But can we write a function silimar to this one, which will create/drop a database and some collections also.

```
func HandleDatabases(){
// for deleting / creating / managing mongoDB databases and collections ?
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using MongoDB, databases and collections do not need to exist prior to using them.

You can run queries against non-existing databases and collections, which will not result in an error, but obviously won't return any documents. When inserting documents into a non-existing database and/or collection, the database and/or collection will be created automatically.

To drop a database, simply use the [`Database.Drop()`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Database.Drop) method. To drop a collection, simply use the [`Collection.Drop()`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Collection.Drop) method.

You only need to create a collection before using it if you want it to create with non-default, special properties. For that, you may use [`Database.CreateCollection()`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Database.CreateCollection).

To find out which databases exist already on the server, you may use the [`Client.ListDatabases()`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Client.ListDatabases) or [`Client.ListDatabaseNames()`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Client.ListDatabaseNames) methods.

To find out which collections exist already in a database, you may use the [`Database.ListCollections()`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Database.ListCollections) or [`Database.ListCollectionNames()`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Database.ListCollectionNames) methods.